# YOLO, cfg or weight file for detect 2 classes

Tags: yolo, yolov5, yolov4, yolov8, yolov7

I have a question regarding YOLO models. I'm looking for weight or cfg files for my YOLO model that specifically detect only 2 classes: 'person' and 'cat'. I'm aware that there are pre-trained models available with 80 classes, but I haven't been able to find the specific file I need. I've searched extensively, but without success. Could anyone suggest a website or resource where I can find the desired files? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!